# How to divide all the elements in a list together

Tags: python, list

For example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
```

I want to do:

```
1/2/3/4/5/6
```

I have tried using the `operator.div` function but it doesn't seem to give the correct result. By the way, I am fairly new to python.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce).

> Apply function of two arguments cumulatively to the items of sequence, from left to right, so as to reduce the sequence to a single value.

The code can be demonstrated as

```
>>> from functools import reduce 
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x/y,l)
0.001388888888888889
```

which is equivalent to

```
>>> 1/2/3/4/5/6
0.001388888888888889
```

---

As `truediv` has already been demonstrated by the other [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38349427/4099593), this is an alternative (the other way is preferred) for Python2

```
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> l = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> reduce(lambda x,y:x/y,l)
0.001388888888888889
```

Comment: Better off using `operator.truediv` here... if the OPs on 2.x, then it'll still have correct behaviour instead of integer division..

Comment: Umm... both got half of the "correct" answer each :)

Comment: Your answer and Kasramvd's answer work perfectly. Thank you for the quick reply! :)

Comment: @bancan You're welcome, Do note that it's better if you accept Kasra's as the correct answer as it is a better way.

Comment: @BhargavRao You just did fine ;-). The `lambda` approach has more flexibility for  variant types of problems.

Comment: @kasra Yup, But your answer is better in this particular case :-)

Comment: Maybe bust let's don't forget that [*Worse is better*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Worse_is_better) ;-)

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`reduce()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#reduce) and `operator.truediv`:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> from operator import truediv
>>> 
>>> reduce(truediv, a)
0.001388888888888889
```

*Note*: In python3.x you need to import the `reduce()` function from from [`functools`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#module-functools) module.

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use a loop?

```
>>> a = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> i = iter(a)
>>> result = next(i)
>>> for num in i:
...     result /= num
...
>>> result
0.001388888888888889
>>> 1/2/3/4/5/6
0.001388888888888889
```